# Count distinct on multiple criteria using FREQUENCY()

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I'm using the formula `=SUM(IF(($C$2:$C$30=O5)*($B$2:$B$30=P3),1/COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$30,O5,$A$2:$A$30,$A$2:$A$30,$B$2:$B$30,P3)),0)` to count how many distinct values on column *A* are such that their value on column *B* equals the value on cell *P3* and their value on column *C* equals their value on cell *O5*. It basically is a count distinct on two criteria.

This is terribly inefficient for when the number of rows is large. I don't want to use pivot tables. I know there's a way to achieve the some result more efficiently using `FREQUENCY()`, but I can't figure it out.
The file I'm playing with is located here:
https://www.sendspace.com/file/u3hchq

How can I do it?

Even though I'm not on Excel 2010, please assume so.

Answer (score 1):

The formula

```
=SUM(--(FREQUENCY(IF((C2:C30=O5)*(B2:B30=P3),MATCH(A2:A30,A2:A30,0)),ROW(A2:A30)-ROW(A2)+1)>0))
```

works.

Comment: This answer might get some upvotes — and, more importantly, will be more useful to other people — if you added an explanation of how and why it works.